# Numeric value shows as empty string when accessing formGroup values?

Tags: javascript, angular

Can someone explain why the numeric values show as an empty string within my formGroup,

```
  private formatFormValues(depositDates) {
    return depositDates.map((depositDate) => {
      console.log('deposit dates', depositDates);
      console.log('deposit dates - amount', depositDate.controls.effectiveDates.value);
      return {
        effectiveDates: depositDate.controls.effectiveDates.value,
        depositDate: depositDate.controls.depositDate.value,
      };
    });
  }
```

I have this `depositDates` formGroup instance which Im logging and looks like this:
[image]

I then try to access the `values` within this instance, and for some reason the `amount` always shows as an empty string despite it being shown as an active and set numeric value?

[image]

Am I in some what missing something / accessing something incorrectly for this to happen?

Comment: Show your html  also

Comment: This is being run on page load fyi

Comment: Is the formGroup expecting a string or a number for amount?  It looks like it is looking for a string.  It could also be an issue with the return not waiting for the map to finish.  I will put a code snippet in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the method returns values before the map function finishes?  You can try the code below..

```
async formatFormValues(depositDates) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(depositDates.map(async (depositDate) => {
                console.log('deposit dates', depositDates);
                console.log('deposit dates - amount', depositDate.controls.effectiveDates.value);
                return {
                    effectiveDates: depositDate.controls.effectiveDates.value,
                    depositDate: depositDate.controls.depositDate.value,
                };
            }));
        });

    }
```

When you access it you can use:

```
this.formatFormValues(depositDates).then(resp => {
    // set form values
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Angular is not being notified to update the `value` of a form group. You can manually call [updateValueAndValidity](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) on your form group or the required form control.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an option param in my `setValue()` call stopping any event emitting, still dont understand why it would access the amount value despite it being there prior to my changes, answer goes to anyone who can explain..